# Is there a word expressing a hostile unwillingness to give someone the benefit of the doubt / consider their viewpoint?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm confronting someone and originally wrote that they didn't care about something. That's what I believe. However I realize I'm asserting how they feel and being extreme; I can't *know* they didn't care.

I'm looking for a word that describes that sort of arguing style--that is, **making an extreme and hostile assertion about something I do not know for a fact, and thereby assuming the worst of someone and/or not allowing for shades of gray**--so I can express how I feel but acknowledge some room for their point of view.

> I want to tell you "you didn't care" but that's unfairly _________. [But I *can* assert] You didn't try to fix it.

I've thought about "contentious", "strongly worded", "belligerent", "unsympathetic", "close-minded", "worked-up", and "dictative". They're all dancing around the concept but not quite right.

--

PS I hope this is an appropriate question. I know it's a very specific concept, but it's common enough I thought it could still be useful to others ;)

Comment: Presumptious, dismissive?

Comment: Intolerance, bigotry, prejudice, chauvinism, contemptuousness, animosity.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the heart of the issue is almost more that you *assumed* something hostile, rather than the *hostility* itself. So perhaps "**assumptive**" would be the right word to fill in your blank there?

Comment: Good point. However maybe 'presumptive' would be even better.

Comment: Yes that's true. Presumptive sounds less archaic than assumptive, and in my opinion also imparts a sense of hostility / negativity too.

Comment: I agree 'presumptive' sounds less archaic, but I think its connotations are closer to inappropriate/forward/disrespectful ('presume') than aggressive/hostile. So it depends on context. For mine I like assumptive: it's neutral (to the point) and its meaning is obvious even if you haven't heard the word before.

Answer (score 1):

I think that to make an unsubstantiated assumption can be more succinctly called ***"unduly judgemental"*** or that your assumption is simply ***"unfounded"***.

Comment: ooh, "judgmental" is good--not my fave answer for the question as a whole but it fits the title perfectly. It brings the 'critical' or 'derogatory' aspects to mind too. However, I'm looking for words for an ungenerous and/or narrow interpretation of data, not for accusations not founded on data at all.

Answer (score 1):

***[Presumptuous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/presumptuous)***

> (Of a person or their behaviour) failing to observe the *limits* of what is permitted or *appropriate*:
>
> - "I hope I won’t be considered presumptuous if I offer some advice"

Close to your context, but with a tweak:

> I want to tell you "you didn't care" but I'm afraid that may be perceived as
> ***presumptuous***.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already hinted at the best word: **confrontational**

Other possibilities:

adversarial

antagonistic

bellicose

combative

contentious

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a word expressing a hostile unwillingness to give someone the benefit of the doubt / consider their viewpoint?

If you don't give someone the benefit of the doubt, or hold a hostile unwillingness to consider their point of view, you are strongly **biased** against that person,

- I want to tell you "you didn't care" but that's an **unfairly biased** view.

> **biased**
>
> - unfairly prejudiced for or against someone or something. [Google](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=biased+definition&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&gfe_rd=cr&ei=digVVrc9oqTzB-iVmugH&gws_rd=ssl)
> - a personal and sometimes unreasoned judgment [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bias%5B1%5D)

- "We will not tolerate this biased media coverage."
- "She is too biased to write about the case objectively."
- "He is biased against women."
- "The judges of the talent show were biased toward musical acts."

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [**'antipathetic'**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/antipathetic):

> Showing or feeling a strong aversion: *it is human nature to be antipathetic to change*  (-- Oxford Dictionaries Online)

although I'm struggling a bit to find a good example where it's used to describe one person's attitude to another...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest **categorical**.

categorical: said in a very strong, clear, and definite way. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/categorical)

*I want to tell you "you didn't care" but that's unfairly categorical.*

Answer (score 0):

**Offensive**: characterized by attack; aggressive; causing resentful displeasure; highly irritating, angering, or annoying.

**Provocative**: tending or serving to provoke; inciting, stimulating, irritating, or vexing; intentionally ​causing an ​angry ​reaction.

Answer (score -2):

*Is there a word expressing a hostile unwillingness to give someone the benefit of the doubt / consider their viewpoint?*

Yes, one might say to such an individual, "Your polemic smacks of arctic scorn."

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: How is arctic scorn not exactly "unwillingness to give someone the benefit of the doubt"?

Comment: Hi Mark, answers here are expected to **explain** and elaborate - that is what my comment is referring to.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it.